# How to write posh a's and g's

Tags: handwriting

Argh, I'm having so much trouble figuring out how to handwrite the a's and g's like the computer does. I learnt on the internet that we changed them in handwriting as we were lazy, which make sense, but I now *need* to know how to properly handwrite them. I just can't do it - especially the g. In all the old handwriting guides from nursery they **never** taught me how to write them like the computer!

So,

> How do you write g's and a's like the computer does?

Comment: I do not understand the question.  Computers do not "write" anything at all by hand. That said, there are many online sources for learning cursive writing (handwriting). You can google them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is is about typography and/or handwriting, now the usage of the English language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because handwriting is not language-specific.

Comment: I write the g by basically writing a Greek letter sigma, then lifting the pen off the page and drawing the tail as a separate stroke. Similarly, you can write the a by drawing the loop first, then another stroke that curves over the top of it and down. Contrary to the posted answer, I don't find these *that* much slower or inconvenient than the normal cursive forms, especially if you're writing neatly and carefully anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called "double-storey" (or "two-storey") letters and are part of medieval calligraphy. They were dropped with the invention of italic and cursive scripts, which were much quicker to write but required better pens than were available to medieval scribes.

I can't understand why you should want to use such formations as part of your general handwriting. You will need to study calligraphy and adopt techniques that will help to preserve letter formation and will inevitably slow you down.

I was taught such a system (italic script) when I learned to write and it held me back for years. Fortunately, I never had to use double-storey letters.

If you want to learn the techniques, there are videos on YouTube.

For your research, see the following Wikipedia articles:

[Wikipedia: Italic script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italic_script)
[Wikipedia: Humanist miniscule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanist_minuscule)

Comment: The question is "How to do it," which this answer doesn't address except via links. It's therefore Not An Answer. However the question is off-topic as handwriting and the shape of letters is not language-specific.

Comment: I use a double story g when handwriting equations. It helps to keep q, g and Greek rho all distinct from one another, which I find difficult otherwise. So that's at least one good reason to want to know how to do it.